# Thread calling problems

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I'm a bit of a newbie at this but I am trying to get the UI on a Reversi game to run on a different thread to the move selection part but I am having some trouble calling the thread on the button click

```
private void playerMoveOKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ReversiT.Invoke();
}

public void ReversiT() {...}
```

Comment: It might help to know what UI framework are you using. Windows Forms, WPF..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58.aspx) to handle everything for me, setting it's `DoWork` event to call your move method (making sure that your move method doesn't touch the UI, or if it has to, invoking the controls on the UI thread).

I'd also set up a method to update the UI on the BackgroundWorker's `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Now on your button click event above, call the BGW's `RunWorkerAsync()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a new thread, you can do something like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(ReversiT);
thread.Start();
```

**[Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)** is used for a different purpose though. It is used to run a method on a specific thread (for instance, if you run a piece of code on a separate thread but want to make UI changes, you will want to use Invoke to make those changes on the UI thread)

Answer (score 0):

You can not invoke a method like that. You can only invoke delegates. Also, calling `Invoke` doesn't spawn a new thread.

You can read [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28VS.71%29.aspx) about delegates, and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28VS.80%29.aspx) about threads. Also, your question leaves much space for discussion:

1. What do you expect from using threads?
2. Have you considered different options for doing background work?

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
this.Invoke(ReversiT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to think about that you are actually trying to achieve here. Running code on a separate thread in a UI is a technique used to stop the UI from hanging. However, some tasks simply have to occur on the UI thread and so can't be run from another thread.

You need to break your logic out such that you can identify which parts need to run on the UI thread (anything that interacts with a control on your UI) and thus anything that can run on a separate thread.

You would end up with code like (as an example):

```
private void playerMoveOKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //thread is merely used as an example
    //you could also use a BackgroundWorker or a task
    var thread = new Thread(NonUiLogic);
    thread.Start();
}

private void NonUiLogic()
{
    ...
    //execute logic that doesn't touch UI
    ...

    BeginInvoke(ReversiT);
}

public void ReversiT() {...}
```

Once you have been through that exercise you may find that there is actually very little that can happen outside of the UI thread and so you really have nothing to gain from using threads.